# A student appeared at 3 examinations.....

Tags: probability

I am very weak in probability, I have a question....

A student appears at $3$ examinations. The probability of passing each exam is $\frac15,\, \frac16,\, \frac17\,$ respectively. Then what is the probability that at least one exam is passed by the student?

Thank for your valuable time...

Comment: If this is difficult, try to simplify the problem first. Consider two exams instead of three. Make the probability of passing equal to $1\over 2$ for each of them. If you can solve this easier case, you can try with three exams instead of two, or with different probabilities for each exam.

Comment: @PerManne: You seem to be deliberately steering the OP away from the standard way of solving such problems!

Comment: @TonyK Maybe. In my experience, the standard way of solving such problems is to search your text for a suitable formula, plug in the numbers, and hope for the best. If you want to understand something, I think it is a good strategy to start with the simplest possible case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$P(Pass\:at\: least \:one\:exam)$

$=1-P(Pass\: no \: exams)$

$=1-\frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{5}{6}\cdot\frac{6}{7}$

$=1-\frac{4}{7}$

$=\frac{3}{7}$

Does this make sense? It looks like the student has a chance...

Answer (score 1):

The de facto method of finding the probability that at least one exam is passed by the student is to find the probability of the complement event.

The probability that at least one exam is

$=1-$ the probability that none exam is passed by the student

$$=1-\left(1-\frac15\right)\left(1-\frac16\right)\left(1-\frac17\right)$$